# System.Diagostics.Stopwatch appears not to display the correct amount of time elapsed

Tags: c#, .net

I am using `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` to time two separate operations in [my program](https://github.com/Sathyaish/Algorithms/blob/master/CSharp/FindPrimesTill/FindPrimesTill/Program.cs).

The program finds all prime numbers till a number input by the user.

When I give it a large input such as 100,000, it reports to have completed each of the two operations in 3 milliseconds each. I know that the algorithms I have written is quite efficient but I doubt it takes only 3 milliseconds.

Sometimes, it takes a long time for each of the two operations but still prints only a very small number of milliseconds as the time elapsed.

This has made me suspicious of something wrong in my profiling code. Could you please tell me if the stopwatch is reporting the right time elapsed? And if it is, why is it that I sometimes see the profiler output appear only after quite a lot of time?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should move `stopwatch.Stop();` after `primesTillN.Count()` because `Count` actually invokes algorithm's execution.

Comment: @AlekseyL.Thank you. You're right. Damn! How could I have missed that. Thanks much. Would you like to write that down as an answer?

Comment: @AlekseyL. But also for the `Print` extension on the `IEnumerable<T>`, the stopwatch reports very low values. That is not a lazy / deferred execution method. I mean, I am not returning a lazy `IEnumerable` from it. I am evaluating the enumerable right in there.

Comment: Can you show the `Print` code?

Comment: Sorry, sure. It's here: https://github.com/Sathyaish/Algorithms/blob/master/CSharp/FindPrimesTill/FindPrimesTill/EnumerableExtensions.cs

Comment: Ok, you're printing `millisecondsToFind` instead of `millisecondsToPrint`

Comment: @AlekseyL. Damn, I am so embarrassed. Thanks much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `FindPrimesTill` only builds "query" (`IEnumerable`) and this query is executed only when `primesTillN.Count()` called (or any other method that forces immediate execution), you should move `stopwatch.Stop()` after `primesTillN.Count()` and you'll get right results.

Comment: An alternative to moving the `stopwatch.Stop()` and `primesTillN.Count()` statements around is to append a `ToList()` call to the end of `FindPrimesTill`, as it will force an immediate evaluation of the query. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Sure (also `Min`, `Max`, `First` and many others), just pointed why stopwatch is reporting wrong time..

Comment: @Adrian Yes, I understand deferred execution. The errors were an oversight on my part, not a lack of understanding. Thanks much.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2, your above comments made that clear even before I added the comment. My comment is for those who do not understand deferred execution who come to this thread not understanding what this actually solves (And therefore a small prompt as to where this answer could be improved.)

Comment: @Adrian Sorry. I wasn't being defensive. Was just trying to explain. Sure, your comment is very helpful. I stand corrected. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I am writing this answer for my own reference to link to the github code.

My initial code was as follows:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int n = 0;

    Console.WriteLine("This program prints all prime numbers till a number you specify.\n");
    Console.Write("Find primes till which number? ");

    var b = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out n);
    if (!b) return;

    var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();
    var primesTillN = FindPrimesTill(n);
    stopwatch.Stop();
    var millisecondsToFind = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    var numFound = primesTillN.Count();

    Console.WriteLine($"\n{numFound} primes between 1 and {n}. Time taken to find primes: {millisecondsToFind} milliseconds");
    Console.WriteLine("Printing...\n");

    stopwatch.Reset();
    stopwatch.Start();
    primesTillN.Print();
    stopwatch.Stop();
    var millisecondsToPrint = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

    Console.WriteLine($"\n\nSTATS:\nTime to find {numFound} primes between 1 to {n}: {millisecondsToFind} milliseconds.");
    Console.WriteLine($"Time taken to print: {millisecondsToFind} milliseconds.\n");

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

As Aleksey pointed out rightly, there were two errors in my code:

1. Since the method `FindPrimesTill` returned a lazily evaluated `IEnumerable<T>`, the stopwatch rightly only counted the time to *build the query*.

   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       ...

   ```
   stopwatch.Start();
   var primesTillN = FindPrimesTill(n);
   stopwatch.Stop();
   var millisecondsToFind = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
   var numFound = primesTillN.Count();

   ...
   ```

   }

One of the two fixes could have worked here:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ...

    stopwatch.Start();
    var primesTillN = FindPrimesTill(n);

    // Put the call to IEnumerable<T>.Count before
    // stopping the stopwatch.
    // Since  Count() is a greedy operator, 
    // it would have executed the query.
    var numFound = primesTillN.Count();

    stopwatch.Stop();
    var millisecondsToFind = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

    ...
}
```

Or:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ...

    stopwatch.Start();

    // Eagerly evaluate the IEnumerable returned
    // by FindPrimesTill by converting it into a List<T>
    var primesTillN = FindPrimesTill(n).ToList();
    stopwatch.Stop();
    var millisecondsToFind = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

    var numFound = primesTillN.Count;
    ...
}
```

2. The second error in my code was that I was printing out the variable `millisecondsToFind` when I should have printed out `millisecondsToPrint` in the second instance to time the `IEnumerable<T>.Print` method call.

   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       ...

   ```
   Console.WriteLine($"Time taken to print: {millisecondsToFind} milliseconds.\n");

   Console.ReadKey();
   ```

   }

Should have been:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ...
    Console.WriteLine($"Time taken to print: {millisecondsToPrint} milliseconds.\n");

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```